# XML Parse To ListBox

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, parsing, listbox

I am trying to get the Names of The Quests added to a ListBox by parsing through an XML document

Example:

```
<EasyQuests>
  <EasyQuest>
    <Name>Example Quest1</Name>
```

So what I would want out of that is "Example Quest1". I then want to add "Example Quest1" to the ListBox.

I also need to get the Action value and the NameClass value from

```
<EasyQuestProfile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <QuestsSorted>
        <QuestsSorted Action="PickUp" NameClass="ExampleQuest1" />
        <QuestsSorted Action="Pulse" NameClass="ExampleQuest1" />
```

So I would need to get PickUp and ExampleQuest1 and Pulse and ExampleQuest1
I would then need to add those values to a SEPARATE list but they need to stay in the same row as in Pulse          ExampleQuest1

This is what I have tried so far and I can't get working.

```
private void btnLoadProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "XML| * .xml";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        path = ofd.FileName;
        xDoc = new XDocument();
        //xDoc.Load(path);
        xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
        var listBoxItems = xDoc.Elements("EasyQuest");
        lstQuestBox.DataSource = listBoxItems.ToList();
        lstQuestBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
        lstQuestBox.ValueMember = "Value";

        var questsSorted = xDoc.Elements("QuestsSorted");
        lstQuestsSorted.DataSource = questsSorted.ToList();
        lstQuestsSorted.DisplayMember = "Value";
        lstQuestsSorted.ValueMember = "Value";



    }
}
```

Here is the XML I am trying to parse through

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EasyQuestProfile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <QuestsSorted>
    <QuestsSorted Action="PickUp" NameClass="ExampleQuest1" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="Pulse" NameClass="ExampleQuest1" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="TurnIn" NameClass="ExampleQuest1" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="PickUp" NameClass="ExampleQuest2" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="Pulse" NameClass="ExampleQuest2" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="TurnIn" NameClass="ExampleQuest2" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="PickUp" NameClass="ExampleQuest3" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="Pulse" NameClass="ExampleQuest3" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="TurnIn" NameClass="ExampleQuest3" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="PickUp" NameClass="ExampleQuest4" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="Pulse" NameClass="ExampleQuest4" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="TurnIn" NameClass="ExampleQuest4" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="PickUp" NameClass="ExampleQuest5" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="Pulse" NameClass="ExampleQuest5" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="TurnIn" NameClass="ExampleQuest5" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="PickUp" NameClass="ExampleQuest6" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="Pulse" NameClass="ExampleQuest6" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="TurnIn" NameClass="ExampleQuest6" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="PickUp" NameClass="ExampleQuest7" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="Pulse" NameClass="ExampleQuest7" />
    <QuestsSorted Action="TurnIn" NameClass="ExampleQuest7" />
  </QuestsSorted>
  <NpcQuest>
    <NPCQuest Id="2055" Name="Master Apothecary Faranell" GameObject="false">
      <PickUpQuests>
        <int>1</int>
        <int>12</int>
        <int>123</int>
        <int>1234</int>
        <int>12345</int>
        <int>123456</int>
        <int>1234567</int>
      </PickUpQuests>
      <TurnInQuests>
        <int>1</int>
        <int>12</int>
        <int>123</int>
        <int>1234</int>
        <int>12345</int>
        <int>123456</int>
        <int>1234567</int>
      </TurnInQuests>
      <Position X="1434.48" Y="404.854" Z="-85.1753" />
    </NPCQuest>
  </NpcQuest>
  <Npc />
  <Blackspots />
  <BlackGuids />
  <EasyQuests>
    <EasyQuest>
      <Name>Example Quest1</Name>
      <QuestId>
        <int>1</int>
      </QuestId>
      <QuestType>None</QuestType>
      <QuestClass />
      <ObjectiveCount1>0</ObjectiveCount1>
      <ObjectiveCount2>0</ObjectiveCount2>
      <ObjectiveCount3>0</ObjectiveCount3>
      <ObjectiveCount4>0</ObjectiveCount4>
      <ObjectiveCount5>0</ObjectiveCount5>
      <ObjectiveCount6>0</ObjectiveCount6>
      <ObjectiveCount7>0</ObjectiveCount7>
      <ObjectiveCount8>0</ObjectiveCount8>
      <ObjectiveCount9>0</ObjectiveCount9>
      <ObjectiveCount10>0</ObjectiveCount10>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount1>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount1>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount2>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount2>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount3>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount3>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount4>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount4>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount5>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount5>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount6>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount6>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount7>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount7>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount8>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount8>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount9>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount9>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount10>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount10>
      <CanCondition></CanCondition>
      <IsCompleteCondition></IsCompleteCondition>
      <RepeatableQuest>false</RepeatableQuest>
      <NotRequiredInQuestLog>false</NotRequiredInQuestLog>
      <PickUpQuestOnItem>false</PickUpQuestOnItem>
      <PickUpQuestOnItemID>0</PickUpQuestOnItemID>
      <Comment></Comment>
      <GossipOptionRewardItem>1</GossipOptionRewardItem>
      <RequiredQuest>0</RequiredQuest>
      <MaxLevel>110</MaxLevel>
      <MinLevel>0</MinLevel>
      <WoWClass>Hunter</WoWClass>
    </EasyQuest>
    <EasyQuest>
      <Name>Example Quest2</Name>
      <QuestId>
        <int>12</int>
      </QuestId>
      <QuestType>KillAndLoot</QuestType>
      <QuestClass xsi:type="KillAndLootEasyQuestClass">
        <HotSpots>
          <Vector3 X="-10872.6" Y="-2170.1" Z="117.256" />
          <Vector3 X="-10811.9" Y="-2195.57" Z="117.256" />
          <Vector3 X="-10844.4" Y="-2121.71" Z="121.006" />
          <Vector3 X="-11145" Y="-2270.49" Z="121.577" />
          <Vector3 X="-11121.4" Y="-2298.59" Z="117.256" />
          <Vector3 X="-10914.9" Y="-2217.93" Z="117.756" />
          <Vector3 X="-10996.2" Y="-2302.69" Z="117.256" />
          <Vector3 X="-10947.9" Y="-2281.99" Z="117.256" />
          <Vector3 X="-10860.2" Y="-2279.32" Z="117.256" />
        </HotSpots>
        <EntryTarget>
          <int>7369</int>
        </EntryTarget>
        <IsGrinderNotQuest>false</IsGrinderNotQuest>
      </QuestClass>
      <ObjectiveCount1>0</ObjectiveCount1>
      <ObjectiveCount2>0</ObjectiveCount2>
      <ObjectiveCount3>0</ObjectiveCount3>
      <ObjectiveCount4>0</ObjectiveCount4>
      <ObjectiveCount5>0</ObjectiveCount5>
      <ObjectiveCount6>0</ObjectiveCount6>
      <ObjectiveCount7>0</ObjectiveCount7>
      <ObjectiveCount8>0</ObjectiveCount8>
      <ObjectiveCount9>0</ObjectiveCount9>
      <ObjectiveCount10>0</ObjectiveCount10>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount1>true</AutoDetectObjectiveCount1>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount2>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount2>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount3>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount3>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount4>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount4>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount5>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount5>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount6>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount6>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount7>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount7>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount8>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount8>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount9>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount9>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount10>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount10>
      <CanCondition></CanCondition>
      <IsCompleteCondition></IsCompleteCondition>
      <RepeatableQuest>false</RepeatableQuest>
      <NotRequiredInQuestLog>false</NotRequiredInQuestLog>
      <PickUpQuestOnItem>false</PickUpQuestOnItem>
      <PickUpQuestOnItemID>0</PickUpQuestOnItemID>
      <Comment></Comment>
      <GossipOptionRewardItem>1</GossipOptionRewardItem>
      <RequiredQuest>0</RequiredQuest>
      <MaxLevel>110</MaxLevel>
      <MinLevel>0</MinLevel>
      <WoWClass>Hunter</WoWClass>
    </EasyQuest>
    <EasyQuest>
      <Name>Example Quest3</Name>
      <QuestId>
        <int>123</int>
      </QuestId>
      <QuestType>UseItemOn</QuestType>
      <QuestClass xsi:type="UseItemOnEasyQuestClass">
        <HotSpots>
          <Vector3 X="-639.344" Y="-4230.19" Z="38.5605" />
        </HotSpots>
        <EntryIdTarget>
          <int>3153</int>
        </EntryIdTarget>
        <ItemId>12345</ItemId>
        <Range>4.5</Range>
      </QuestClass>
      <ObjectiveCount1>0</ObjectiveCount1>
      <ObjectiveCount2>0</ObjectiveCount2>
      <ObjectiveCount3>0</ObjectiveCount3>
      <ObjectiveCount4>0</ObjectiveCount4>
      <ObjectiveCount5>0</ObjectiveCount5>
      <ObjectiveCount6>0</ObjectiveCount6>
      <ObjectiveCount7>0</ObjectiveCount7>
      <ObjectiveCount8>0</ObjectiveCount8>
      <ObjectiveCount9>0</ObjectiveCount9>
      <ObjectiveCount10>0</ObjectiveCount10>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount1>true</AutoDetectObjectiveCount1>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount2>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount2>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount3>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount3>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount4>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount4>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount5>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount5>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount6>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount6>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount7>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount7>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount8>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount8>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount9>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount9>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount10>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount10>
      <CanCondition></CanCondition>
      <IsCompleteCondition></IsCompleteCondition>
      <RepeatableQuest>false</RepeatableQuest>
      <NotRequiredInQuestLog>false</NotRequiredInQuestLog>
      <PickUpQuestOnItem>false</PickUpQuestOnItem>
      <PickUpQuestOnItemID>0</PickUpQuestOnItemID>
      <Comment></Comment>
      <GossipOptionRewardItem>1</GossipOptionRewardItem>
      <RequiredQuest>0</RequiredQuest>
      <MaxLevel>110</MaxLevel>
      <MinLevel>0</MinLevel>
      <WoWClass>Hunter</WoWClass>
    </EasyQuest>
    <EasyQuest>
      <Name>Example Quest4</Name>
      <QuestId>
        <int>1234</int>
      </QuestId>
      <QuestType>UseSpellOn</QuestType>
      <QuestClass xsi:type="UseSpellOnEasyQuestClass">
        <HotSpots>
          <Vector3 X="-639.344" Y="-4230.19" Z="38.5605" />
        </HotSpots>
        <EntryIdTarget>
          <int>3153</int>
        </EntryIdTarget>
        <SpellId>1234</SpellId>
        <Range>4.5</Range>
      </QuestClass>
      <ObjectiveCount1>0</ObjectiveCount1>
      <ObjectiveCount2>0</ObjectiveCount2>
      <ObjectiveCount3>0</ObjectiveCount3>
      <ObjectiveCount4>0</ObjectiveCount4>
      <ObjectiveCount5>0</ObjectiveCount5>
      <ObjectiveCount6>0</ObjectiveCount6>
      <ObjectiveCount7>0</ObjectiveCount7>
      <ObjectiveCount8>0</ObjectiveCount8>
      <ObjectiveCount9>0</ObjectiveCount9>
      <ObjectiveCount10>0</ObjectiveCount10>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount1>true</AutoDetectObjectiveCount1>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount2>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount2>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount3>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount3>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount4>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount4>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount5>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount5>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount6>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount6>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount7>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount7>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount8>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount8>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount9>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount9>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount10>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount10>
      <CanCondition></CanCondition>
      <IsCompleteCondition></IsCompleteCondition>
      <RepeatableQuest>false</RepeatableQuest>
      <NotRequiredInQuestLog>false</NotRequiredInQuestLog>
      <PickUpQuestOnItem>false</PickUpQuestOnItem>
      <PickUpQuestOnItemID>0</PickUpQuestOnItemID>
      <Comment></Comment>
      <GossipOptionRewardItem>1</GossipOptionRewardItem>
      <RequiredQuest>0</RequiredQuest>
      <MaxLevel>110</MaxLevel>
      <MinLevel>0</MinLevel>
      <WoWClass>Hunter</WoWClass>
    </EasyQuest>
    <EasyQuest>
      <Name>Example Quest5</Name>
      <QuestId>
        <int>12345</int>
      </QuestId>
      <QuestType>InteractWithNpc</QuestType>
      <QuestClass xsi:type="InteractWithNpcEasyQuestClass">
        <HotSpots>
          <Vector3 X="-639.344" Y="-4230.19" Z="38.5605" />
        </HotSpots>
        <GossipOptionNpcInteractWith>1</GossipOptionNpcInteractWith>
        <Macro></Macro>
        <IgnoreIfDead>false</IgnoreIfDead>
        <EntryIdTarget>
          <int>3153</int>
        </EntryIdTarget>
        <Range>4.5</Range>
      </QuestClass>
      <ObjectiveCount1>0</ObjectiveCount1>
      <ObjectiveCount2>0</ObjectiveCount2>
      <ObjectiveCount3>0</ObjectiveCount3>
      <ObjectiveCount4>0</ObjectiveCount4>
      <ObjectiveCount5>0</ObjectiveCount5>
      <ObjectiveCount6>0</ObjectiveCount6>
      <ObjectiveCount7>0</ObjectiveCount7>
      <ObjectiveCount8>0</ObjectiveCount8>
      <ObjectiveCount9>0</ObjectiveCount9>
      <ObjectiveCount10>0</ObjectiveCount10>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount1>true</AutoDetectObjectiveCount1>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount2>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount2>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount3>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount3>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount4>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount4>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount5>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount5>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount6>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount6>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount7>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount7>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount8>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount8>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount9>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount9>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount10>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount10>
      <CanCondition></CanCondition>
      <IsCompleteCondition></IsCompleteCondition>
      <RepeatableQuest>false</RepeatableQuest>
      <NotRequiredInQuestLog>false</NotRequiredInQuestLog>
      <PickUpQuestOnItem>false</PickUpQuestOnItem>
      <PickUpQuestOnItemID>0</PickUpQuestOnItemID>
      <Comment></Comment>
      <GossipOptionRewardItem>1</GossipOptionRewardItem>
      <RequiredQuest>0</RequiredQuest>
      <MaxLevel>110</MaxLevel>
      <MinLevel>0</MinLevel>
      <WoWClass>Hunter</WoWClass>
    </EasyQuest>
    <EasyQuest>
      <Name>Example Quest6</Name>
      <QuestId>
        <int>123456</int>
      </QuestId>
      <QuestType>FollowNpc</QuestType>
      <QuestClass xsi:type="FollowNpcEasyQuestClass">
        <StartPosition X="-639.344" Y="-4230.19" Z="38.5605" />
        <NpcEntry>3153</NpcEntry>
        <Assist>true</Assist>
        <FollowDistance>5</FollowDistance>
      </QuestClass>
      <ObjectiveCount1>0</ObjectiveCount1>
      <ObjectiveCount2>0</ObjectiveCount2>
      <ObjectiveCount3>0</ObjectiveCount3>
      <ObjectiveCount4>0</ObjectiveCount4>
      <ObjectiveCount5>0</ObjectiveCount5>
      <ObjectiveCount6>0</ObjectiveCount6>
      <ObjectiveCount7>0</ObjectiveCount7>
      <ObjectiveCount8>0</ObjectiveCount8>
      <ObjectiveCount9>0</ObjectiveCount9>
      <ObjectiveCount10>0</ObjectiveCount10>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount1>true</AutoDetectObjectiveCount1>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount2>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount2>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount3>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount3>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount4>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount4>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount5>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount5>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount6>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount6>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount7>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount7>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount8>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount8>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount9>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount9>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount10>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount10>
      <CanCondition></CanCondition>
      <IsCompleteCondition></IsCompleteCondition>
      <RepeatableQuest>false</RepeatableQuest>
      <NotRequiredInQuestLog>false</NotRequiredInQuestLog>
      <PickUpQuestOnItem>false</PickUpQuestOnItem>
      <PickUpQuestOnItemID>0</PickUpQuestOnItemID>
      <Comment></Comment>
      <GossipOptionRewardItem>1</GossipOptionRewardItem>
      <RequiredQuest>0</RequiredQuest>
      <MaxLevel>110</MaxLevel>
      <MinLevel>0</MinLevel>
      <WoWClass>Hunter</WoWClass>
    </EasyQuest>
    <EasyQuest>
      <Name>Example Quest7</Name>
      <QuestId>
        <int>1234567</int>
      </QuestId>
      <QuestType>Gatherer</QuestType>
      <QuestClass xsi:type="GathererEasyQuestClass">
        <HotSpots>
          <Vector3 X="-489.093" Y="-4301.17" Z="42.8668" />
          <Vector3 X="-406.266" Y="-4279.2" Z="46.376" />
          <Vector3 X="-487.607" Y="-4277.06" Z="43.0128" />
          <Vector3 X="-326.03" Y="-4395.06" Z="58.3265" />
          <Vector3 X="-486.916" Y="-4291.01" Z="43.2161" />
          <Vector3 X="-404.261" Y="-4263.58" Z="49.3811" />
          <Vector3 X="-360.679" Y="-4337.94" Z="58.1938" />
          <Vector3 X="-556.425" Y="-4288.72" Z="37.4423" />
          <Vector3 X="-422.731" Y="-4377.85" Z="42.2301" />
          <Vector3 X="-551.576" Y="-4292.26" Z="37.0935" />
          <Vector3 X="-592.091" Y="-4074.48" Z="74.4737" />
          <Vector3 X="-444.979" Y="-4122.43" Z="51.091" />
          <Vector3 X="-244.933" Y="-4318.93" Z="61.35" />
          <Vector3 X="-295.805" Y="-4337.23" Z="56.8324" />
          <Vector3 X="-465.098" Y="-4381.39" Z="50.5997" />
          <Vector3 X="-406.41" Y="-4460.83" Z="51.9784" />
          <Vector3 X="-423.568" Y="-4175.42" Z="50.8418" />
          <Vector3 X="-516.889" Y="-4187.04" Z="77.1396" />
          <Vector3 X="-746.487" Y="-4276.66" Z="43.7713" />
          <Vector3 X="-422.691" Y="-4187.55" Z="51.6474" />
          <Vector3 X="-469.634" Y="-4378.43" Z="48.3773" />
          <Vector3 X="-413.091" Y="-4398.37" Z="43.5909" />
          <Vector3 X="-407.968" Y="-4061.42" Z="51.8647" />
          <Vector3 X="-317.47" Y="-4438.41" Z="57.4445" />
          <Vector3 X="-674.292" Y="-4300.25" Z="44.9458" />
          <Vector3 X="-427.711" Y="-4185.25" Z="50.4451" />
          <Vector3 X="-601.576" Y="-4075.62" Z="75.8641" />
          <Vector3 X="-322.206" Y="-4438.69" Z="56.7659" />
          <Vector3 X="-408.213" Y="-4395.52" Z="42.7661" />
          <Vector3 X="-317.603" Y="-4105.12" Z="54.3323" />
          <Vector3 X="-489.684" Y="-4089.52" Z="64.5607" />
          <Vector3 X="-182.636" Y="-4183.35" Z="81.1131" />
          <Vector3 X="-489.837" Y="-4464.14" Z="51.9806" />
          <Vector3 X="-330.869" Y="-4393.1" Z="58.5324" />
          <Vector3 X="-298.444" Y="-4332.24" Z="56.6012" />
          <Vector3 X="-482.637" Y="-4083.92" Z="65.4204" />
          <Vector3 X="-183.5" Y="-4181.8" Z="80.8193" />
          <Vector3 X="-261.121" Y="-4159.08" Z="54.927" />
          <Vector3 X="-255.695" Y="-4160.31" Z="55.8644" />
          <Vector3 X="-475.429" Y="-4323.95" Z="44.0192" />
          <Vector3 X="-260.522" Y="-4211.04" Z="58.7291" />
          <Vector3 X="-523.076" Y="-4182.39" Z="76.9361" />
          <Vector3 X="-413.362" Y="-4058.05" Z="52.3058" />
          <Vector3 X="-364.977" Y="-4333.73" Z="55.1878" />
          <Vector3 X="-696.942" Y="-4355.8" Z="54.1846" />
        </HotSpots>
        <EntryIdObjects>
          <int>171938</int>
        </EntryIdObjects>
      </QuestClass>
      <ObjectiveCount1>0</ObjectiveCount1>
      <ObjectiveCount2>0</ObjectiveCount2>
      <ObjectiveCount3>0</ObjectiveCount3>
      <ObjectiveCount4>0</ObjectiveCount4>
      <ObjectiveCount5>0</ObjectiveCount5>
      <ObjectiveCount6>0</ObjectiveCount6>
      <ObjectiveCount7>0</ObjectiveCount7>
      <ObjectiveCount8>0</ObjectiveCount8>
      <ObjectiveCount9>0</ObjectiveCount9>
      <ObjectiveCount10>0</ObjectiveCount10>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount1>true</AutoDetectObjectiveCount1>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount2>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount2>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount3>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount3>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount4>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount4>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount5>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount5>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount6>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount6>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount7>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount7>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount8>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount8>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount9>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount9>
      <AutoDetectObjectiveCount10>false</AutoDetectObjectiveCount10>
      <CanCondition></CanCondition>
      <IsCompleteCondition></IsCompleteCondition>
      <RepeatableQuest>false</RepeatableQuest>
      <NotRequiredInQuestLog>false</NotRequiredInQuestLog>
      <PickUpQuestOnItem>false</PickUpQuestOnItem>
      <PickUpQuestOnItemID>0</PickUpQuestOnItemID>
      <Comment></Comment>
      <GossipOptionRewardItem>1</GossipOptionRewardItem>
      <RequiredQuest>0</RequiredQuest>
      <MaxLevel>110</MaxLevel>
      <MinLevel>0</MinLevel>
      <WoWClass>Hunter</WoWClass>
    </EasyQuest>
  </EasyQuests>
</EasyQuestProfile>
```

Comment: so what is the problem? what is not working?

Comment: The document loads but I am not getting anything imported into the GUI list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Elements` looks for direct children so it will not work like that. You need to tell it exactly whose children like this:

```
xDoc.Elements("EasyQuestProfile").Elements("EasyQuests").Elements("EasyQuest");
```

You can use `Descendants` if you want since it will look for children, grand children and so on. You can do it like this:

```
var listBoxItems = xDoc.Descendants("EasyQuest").Select(x => x.Element("Name").Value);
lstQuestBox.DataSource = listBoxItems.ToList();

var questsSorted = xDoc.Descendants("QuestsSorted").Descendants("QuestsSorted")
    .Select(x => x.Attribute("Action").Value + " : " + x.Attribute("NameClass").Value);
lstQuestsSorted.DataSource = questsSorted.ToList();
```

`Elements` is faster performance wise but you do not need to worry since you do not have a huge file and you are not doing many times.

Comment: Hmm its still not appending to the list boxes, also when I debug nothing is filling up its null.

Comment: When you debug, is there anything in `listBoxItems`?

Comment: Hey so lets say I edit the content in the List boxes, will it change the xml in the background?

Comment: No it will not. But that's possible. If you need help with that just post another question please and I or someone else can help you with it.